# How to draw the small signal equivalent of this circuit?

Tags: small-signal

[image: My circuit]

[image: My small signal circuit]

I need to convert this circuit into a small signal circuit but I am having a hard time drawing it. I think it is wrong at the FET-transistor connection to the bipolar-transistor.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.